# Replacing a subset of rows in pandas dataframe with a Series object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column, `data['sign']` that is `+/-1` when the value in `data['quantity']` is positive/negative. When I try to convert the values in `data['quantity']` according to their sign in the `data['sign']` column, it doesn't work:

```
data.loc[data.sign == -1, 'quantity'] = data.loc[data.sign == -1, 'quantity'].apply(lambda x: -1*x)
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: @JoeR Oh crap, I realized my mistake... the original column had another data type so it got messed up by the casting. :( Looks like my code snippet works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
data['quantity'] = data['sign'] * data['quantity']
```

Comment: This works too, I'll accept it, although my mistake was ill-posed (as Joe R had led me to this discovery: my snippet works but it's just that the data type of the column that was incorrect).

Comment: @Katie, next time delete your question, this issue will likely not come up again for someone else.. ;)